# Can't get form data in view function: Django

Tags: python, django, post, drop-down-menu

I need to submit a string to a view function via a dropdown menu and submit button.

in my template I have:

```
<form action="{% url 'exec_task' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <select id="select_task" form="select_task" name="select_task">
        {% for task in available_tasks %}
          <option id="selected_task" value="{{ task }}">{{ task }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Run Selected Task">
</form>
```

in my view function I have:

```
def exec_task(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    task = request.POST.get('select_task')
    print(task)
    getattr(tasks, task)(0)
  return redirect('management')
```

The print(task) always comes out as None, which generates an error when I try to call it via getattr in the next line.

I've read through all the questions and tutorials I can find on this and I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but when I print the request.POST object, all I get is the csrf token. The QueryDict has nothing else in it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check `form.is_valid()` in view and after this get `select_task` like this: `form.cleaned_data['select_task']`

Comment: Post your `available_tasks` values here also remove `form="select_task"` from select tag.

Comment: Check what you have in request.POST dictionary by a breakpoint or print statetment

Comment: @AnupYadav thanks! that was the issue, as soon as I removed the form declaration in the select tag it worked. Why is this? can you explain what the form declaration is for and why it was preventing this from working.

Comment: @JonhyBeebop Thanks, but I'm not using a Django ModelForm.

Comment: @YugandharChaudhari, as stated in the question, the request.POST only contained the csrf token.

Comment: Actually in browser it was taking as tag and that parsing was getting neglected. You can use `for` NOT  `form` as html5 allows that.

Comment: Should I add this as answer so you can accept?

Comment: @AnupYadav yea, please do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in comments please remove

`form="select_task"` from select tag.

So final select tag / html would be.

```
<form action="{% url 'exec_task' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <select id="select_task" name="select_task">
        {% for task in available_tasks %}
          <option id="selected_task" value="{{ task }}">{{ task }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Run Selected Task">
</form>
```